# Excel ignoring code that works in other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that runs in several other workbooks but seems to be ignored in a specific one.

The only difference I can see between the ones that work and the one that doesn't, is a line that has `SaveAs Filename:` vs `SaveAs FileName:`. Somehow I cannot imagine that would cause the whole script to be ignored but??

The other thing is when I attempt to change the code from `Filename` to `FileName`, excel changes it back as soon as I go to the next line.

Corrupt file?

Apologies for the sloppy code... :(

````
```Sub Create_Individual_Files()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False




    Dim i               As Integer
    Dim x               As String
    Dim Lastrow         As Long
    Dim NewBook         As Workbook
    Dim Sourcewb        As Workbook: Set Sourcewb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim FileExtStr      As String
    Dim FileFormatNum   As Long
    Dim FName           As String
    Dim Fpath           As String
    Dim FName2          As String

        Fpath = Sheets("Variables").Range("B1").Text
        FName = Sheets("Variables").Range("B9").Text
        FName2 = Sheets("Variables").Range("B2").Text

    'Find the last row of data in each  tab.
    Lastrow = Sourcewb.Sheets(1).Cells(Sourcewb.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    'This section creates each new file, retaining all formulas, from the existing tabs in the master workbook. Then saves the file with the individuals name.
    For i = 2 To Lastrow
        x = Sourcewb.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value
        Sourcewb.Sheets(Array("Summary", "Pivot", "Data", "Modifier %", "Modifier Dollar", "Variables")).Copy
        Set NewBook = ActiveWorkbook
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        With NewBook
            .SaveAs Filename:=Fpath & FName2 & "-" & x & FName & ".xlsx"
            '.Close False


        End With



    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'The section below deletes data from each tab that is not specific to the individual.

    Sheets("Variables").Select
'    Range("C5").Select
'    Selection.Copy
    Range("B10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = x
'    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("Summary").Select
    Call Loop_Delete_Summary
        Sheets("Data").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Unlist
    Call Loop_Delete_Summary
        Sheets("Modifier %").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Unlist
    Call Delete_Modifier_Percent
        Sheets("Modifier Dollar").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Unlist
    Call Loop_Delete_Summary
        'Sheets("Controls").Select
        Sheets("Variables").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Call ResetCursor


    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
         Next i



        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub```







```Sub Loop_Delete_Summary()

    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim rng As Range




    With ActiveSheet


        .Select

        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView


        'Set the first and last row to loop through
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Offset(1).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

        'Loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

            'Check the values in the A column
            With .Cells(Lrow, "A")

                If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                    If .Value <> Worksheets("Variables").Range("B10") Then


                        If rng Is Nothing Then
                            Set rng = .Cells
                        Else
                            Set rng = Application.Union(rng, .Cells)
                        End If
                    End If

                End If
            End With

        Next Lrow

    End With

    'Delete all rows at once
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With




End Sub```







```Sub Loop_Delete_Modifier_Percent()
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
    'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
    With ActiveSheet

        'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
        .Select

        'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
        'back to normal view, we do this for speed
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'Set the first and last row to loop through
        Firstrow = 2
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

            'We check the values in the A column in this example
            With .Cells(Lrow, "B")

                If Not IsError(.Value) Then

Select Case .Value
Case Is <> Worksheets("Variables").Range("B10").Value: .EntireRow.Delete
End Select

                End If

            End With

        Next Lrow

    End With

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub```
````

*****The code when using F8 to step through seems to skip over this section...*****

````
``` x = Sourcewb.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value
        Sourcewb.Sheets(Array("Summary", "Pivot", "Data", "Modifier %", "Modifier Dollar", "Variables")).Copy
        Set NewBook = ActiveWorkbook
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        With NewBook
            .SaveAs Filename:=Fpath & FName2 & "-" & x & FName & ".xlsx"
            '.Close False


        End With


   Sheets("Variables").Select
'    Range("C5").Select
'    Selection.Copy
    Range("B10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = x
'    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("Summary").Select
    Call Loop_Delete_Summary
        Sheets("Data").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Unlist
    Call Loop_Delete_Summary
        Sheets("Modifier %").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Unlist
    Call Delete_Modifier_Percent
        Sheets("Modifier Dollar").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Unlist
    Call Loop_Delete_Summary
        'Sheets("Controls").Select
        Sheets("Variables").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Call ResetCursor


         Next i```
````

Comment: Add a new variable: `Dim FileName`, then immediately delete, to "fix" the capitalization. But as far as your other question, we'd need more detail (i.e. the code in question that is "ignored"). Otherwise we really can't help.

Comment: If the capitalization changes then some where you have declared that as a variable,sub,function,module,...

Comment: The code when using F8 to step through seems to skip over this section... See above

Comment: If make the code less 'sloppy', with proper indenting, issues may become more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the order of the tabs was the issue. I noticed  that `Lastrow = Sourcewb.Sheets(1).Cells(Sourcewb.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Lastrow = 0.

I moved the front 2 tabs which had no data to the end of the tabs and it works.

Otherwise, for whatever reason, it would find zero as the last row and simply skip to the end.